# CSS styling on active link works briefly then stops

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have the following links which are in a list. The styling works when they are clicked but when the page loads to the href location the styling doesn't show

```js
$('.sidebar-nav li').on('click', function() {
  $('li').removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
});
```

```css
.hello {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li><i class="icon-home"></i><a href="{{route('dashboard')}}">Home</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-user"></i><a href=""> Profile</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="">Tags</a>
    <ul id="task-ul">
      <li><a style="color:#e62a76" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i>Personal</a></li>
      <li><a style="color:#774898" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i> Meetings</a></li>
      <li><a style="color:turquoise" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i>Email/call</a></li>
      <li><a style="color:#fbb901" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i> Follow up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><i class="icon-calendar"></i><a href="">Events</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><a href="">Productivity</a></li>
  <li><i class="icon-signout"></i><a href="">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--end of sidebar-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking the link you're doing the action of going to a new url, which reloads the page and thus resets all your styles.

In your particular case I'd consider something like this:

```
$('.sidebar-nav li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.sidebar-nav li a').removeClass('hello');
  $(this).addClass('hello');
});
```

By putting the event handler on the `a` tag, you can run `preventDefault()` on the event and that would stop the page from moving to a new url and reloading.

If you wanted the change the class on the `li` still rather than the `a` tag, then you could just do some DOM traversal to access the `li` that you want. Something like `$(this).parent('li').addClass()`, I think will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be adding css classes programatically using jquery/javascript for active link. You can do it just using css:

.sidebar-nav li a:active {border-bottom: 2px solid blue !important;}

Try and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using Laravel framework
so instead of using jquery to add Class hello you could try this

```
    @php
        $current_route_name = Route::currentRouteName();
    @endphp

    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li <?php  if($current_route_name  == 'dashboard') echo 'class="hello"' ?> ><i class="icon-home"></i><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Home</a></li>
        <li><i class="icon-user"></i><a href=""> Profile</a></li>
        <li><i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="">Tags</a>
            <ul id="task-ul">
                <li ><a style="color:#e62a76" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i>Personal</a></li>
                <li><a style="color:#774898" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i> Meetings</a></li>
                <li ><a style="color:turquoise" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i>Email/call</a></li>
                <li><a style="color:#fbb901" href=""><i class="icon-circle"></i> Follow up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><i class="icon-calendar"></i><a href="">Events</a></li>
        <li><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i><a href="">Productivity</a></li>
        <li><i class="icon-signout"></i><a href="">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

It will get current route name and match with the anchors route name and add class based on that route

Comment: How are you making this assumption?

Comment: Actually his html belongs to the syntax of a kind of laravel so in order to achieve this goal in laravel with the page redirection i have used this